# Django: Mock a field on a model

Tags: python, django

How do I assign a mock object to the user field on this model? Is the anyway to bypass the '"SomeModel.user" must be a "User" instance' check?

```
 class SomeModel(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I am not saving this model it's purely for unit testing a method on that model. I also don't want to create a real User model.

Comment: Can't you just use: SomeModel.user = User() ?

Comment: I want to assert certain methods on the user object.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

You can't really bypass that check. The closest you can get is:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use `unittest.patch` to mock a property:

```
class TestThing(django.test.TestCase):
    @unittest.patch('my_app.models.SomeModel.user', new_callable=unittest.PropertyMock)
    def test_thing(self, user_field):
        user_field.return_value = 5
        ...
```

This works on Django fields.