# Using mock objects to test Python/Django models

Tags: python, django, mocking

I'm building some Django models I'd like to test. I'm trying to avoid having to create lots of unnecessary objects purely to run unit tests. I thought unittest.mock might help with this but I'm really struggling to understand its operation. All the tutorial examples seem to relate to mocking external API calls which is a use case I think I understand but I'm beginning to think either it might not be applicable to my situation or I'm just misunderstanding it completely. This is a typical model:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar, models.RESTRICT)
     ...other FKs
    baz = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    
    def do_something(self):
        return True if self.baz > 10 else False
```

And my issue is I want to test do_something() but I don't want to create a full Foo object with objects for all those FKs. I was hoping I could do something like this, but clearly I've got something wrong along the way.

```
@patch('models.foo.Foo')   
class FooTestCase(TestCase):
 
    def test_foo_do_something(self, foo):
        f = foo() 
        f.baz = 20
        self.assertTrue(f.do_something())
```

Can anyone show me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You'd have to do `null=True` on the other fields to avoid having to populate them, then just change it back when you're done.

Comment: Have you tried factory boy to create your test instaces: https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes.html

Comment: I haven't but will take a look. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54936279/841339) may help you!

Comment: Do you actually need to set those foreign keys (do you need to save)? Depending on what you're testing on the model, you can often get away with creating a class instance but never saving it to the database: f = Foo().  The validators never get run, so you can focus on the properties you care about.

Comment: No, I don't need to save. What you've described is exactly what I'm trying to achieve. I think my issue is I don't understand how the mock object works to then test the properties. How do I set a property (e.g. baz above) and then test a function that relies on that property (e.g. do_something()) The example above passes but I think only because f.do_something() evaluates as truthy. If I test for false by passing in f.baz = 0, the test fails.

Comment: In the end I've done exactly what you suggested @TimNyborg. Thanks. For most things I don't need to save so I'm just testing with f = Foo(). Still not exactly sure what to do when things rely on foreign keys but I might give hendrikschneider's suggestion of factoryboy a go.